# Core Data - NSDate property changing while in the persistent store

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I'm developing a calendar app which saves and displays various shift rotations. I've been banging by head against the wall the last few days after recent unexplained errors that strangely coincided with an X-Code update to ver. 4.5.2. I couldn't find any similar issues anywhere on Google or Stackoveflow.

The shift rotations are set and saved by the user. The process of creating a shift rotation involves presenting a user with a range of dates, and the user associating each date with a particular shift.

I'm using Core Data with a sqlite store to manage the saved data. The object graph for the above elements involve  several "Shift" NSManagedObject entities which contain the details of a shift, such as title, start and end times, and most importantly a date which allows the shift rotation to be displayed later. The "Shift" entities are kept together by another NSManagedObject called "ShiftRotation" which has a many-to-one relationship to the "Shifts".

My app was working properly until recently, when I made few changes to how I was using these "Shift" objects.

My problem is this. The user associates a "Shift" to a date. The date is stored inside a "date" property within the "Shift" NSManagedObject. The context is saved. When I access the "Shift" later, without making any changes, the date that was assigned to the "Shift" appears changed.

I went through my code line by line and added numerous NSLogs to see where or why it's changing, with no results. I noticed that there is no change to the date immediately before AND after I save the context within the class where the save is occurring. There's also no change when I access it from the main Calendar screen. However when I later retrieve the "Shifts" from another screen where I manage all shift rotations, they appear to have changed.

The date change is approximately 31 to 32 days in the future. I can't help but wonder if this is a bug in Core Data or I'm a missing something.

Any explanation or reason why accessing a date from a sqlite persistent store causes a significant and unpredictable date change?

**Update:** I tried to further narrow down what was happening and where it was happening by using NSNotificationCenter.

I'm using iOS 6.

I registered the root view controller to observe any changes to the managed object context. Particularly any changes to the Objects (i.e. NSManagedObjectContextObjectDidChange).

After I updated the properties of the "Shift" NSManagedObject I receive a notification indicating that the "Shift" object was updated. Here's some code and logs.

This is where the "Shift" entity is created and given a date:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)arrayWithDateStartingAtDate:(NSDate *)anyDate forNumberOfDays:(NSUInteger)days;
{
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSMutableArray *monthArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    NSDate *tempDate;

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[CSEventStore sharedStore] managedObjectContext];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < days; i++) {
        [comps setDay:i];
        tempDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:anyDate options:0];
        Shift *shiftRDO = [Shift initShiftEntityRDOWithDate:tempDate InContext:moc];
        [shiftRDO setShiftRotation:_shiftRotation];

        NSMutableDictionary *dateDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:tempDate, @"date", shiftRDO, @"shift", nil];
        [monthArray addObject:dateDict];
    }

    return monthArray;
}
```

This is where the call is made to update it:

```
[shiftEntity updateWithShiftType:_selectedShiftType inContext:context];
```

Which calls the method:

```
- (void)updateWithShiftType:(ShiftType *)shiftType inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",shiftType.title];
    self.symbol = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",shiftType.symbol];
    self.startTime = [shiftType.startTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:0];
    self.endTime = [shiftType.endTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:0];
    self.splitStartTime = [shiftType.splitStartTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:0];
    self.splitEndTime = [shiftType.splitEndTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:0];
    self.isWorkday = [shiftType.isWorkday copy];
    self.isTimeOff = [shiftType.isTimeOff copy];
    self.typeID = [shiftType typeID];
}
```

After the above code executes, the first notification is posted in the log:

```
<Shift: 0x8140b70> (entity: Shift; id: 0x81409e0 <x-coredata:///Shift/tE59A199A-444E-4079-BD8C-0D3E734607783> ; data: {
date = "2012-10-29 04:00:00 +0000";
endTime = "2012-11-02 19:35:38 +0000";
isTimeOff = 0;
isWorkday = 1;
shiftRotation = "0x81406a0 <x-coredata:///ShiftRotation/tE59A199A-444E-4079-BD8C-0D3E734607782>";
splitEndTime = nil;
splitStartTime = nil;
startTime = "2012-11-02 09:35:34 +0000";
symbol = none;
title = Days;
typeID = "991ACC8C-ECE0-4555-9002-7AC233F26CBF";
```

The "**date**" property does have the proper assigned date.

Now as soon as I save the context with the following method:

```
- (BOOL)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (__managedObjectContext) {
        if ([__managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![__managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

            // More details on error
            NSArray* detailedErrors = [error userInfo][NSDetailedErrorsKey];
            if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0) {
                for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors) {
                    NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
                }
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"  %@", [error userInfo]);
            }

            return NO;
            abort();
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I receive a second notification of a change with the following log:

```
    <Shift: 0x8140b70> (entity: Shift; id: 0x82c9dd0 <x-coredata://7CE834F9-5056-457A-BB2C-B8BA638086F1/Shift/p23> ; data: {
    date = "2012-12-02 05:00:00 +0000";
    endTime = "2012-11-02 19:35:38 +0000";
    isTimeOff = 0;
    isWorkday = 1;
    shiftRotation = "0x8260dc0 <x-coredata://7CE834F9-5056-457A-BB2C-B8BA638086F1/ShiftRotation/p11>";
    splitEndTime = nil;
    splitStartTime = nil;
    startTime = "2012-11-02 09:35:34 +0000";
    symbol = none;
    title = Days;
    typeID = "991ACC8C-ECE0-4555-9002-7AC233F26CBF";
}),
```

As you notice, the "**date**" changed to 2012-12-02, just by saving.

**Update:** I was finally able to track the cause of the unexplained change. It seems that I was inadvertently changing the "date" property after I was saving the context somewhere else in my code. Perhaps that would have not happened if I had followed carmin's convention (I would have given +1 if I had the reputation). The value was not changing in the Persistent store after all.

Perhaps sharing how I tracked down this bug might benefit anyone else that might have similar problems, not necessarily related to Core Data.

I used Key Value Observing, to observe the "date" property. I began observing immediately after creating the "Shift" entity:

```
[_shiftEntity addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"date" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

...and stopped observing after a point in my code where the change had already occurred:

```
[_shiftEntity removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"date" context:NULL];
```

I then implemented the KVO method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"Object being observed: %@", [object description]);
    NSLog(@"Value changed to: %@", change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]);
}
```

I placed a break point at the above method. When the change occurred, it stopped at this point, and told me what had change. Most importantly, when the code stopped executing, I looked at the call stack, and traced my way back through the path that the code took that caused the change. I was able to find exactly where my code was making the change.

I don't have much knowledge using KVO but this experience showed me its usefulness even for debugging purposes.

Comment: Can you post your code and also let us know which iOS are using?

Comment: NSLog every instance of getting/setting the value. Also please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible naming conflict.  I have learned to prefix all my names.  For example, I call a core data property "pDate" instead of "date".  I call a stack local "zDate", a parameter "aDate", a static "sDate", and an instance variable "iDate".  (I do not prefix method names.)  This avoids variable naming conflicts and makes code much easier to understand.  Giving something a simple name is to look for a name conflict with the OS which should prefix all of its variables with __ (a double underscore), but that does not always happen.  This may not be your problem, but it is possible that the OS uses the term "date" for another purpose and it seems to be modifying "date" to the time of save.